# How to get an user input and use the value inside method?

Tags: java, methods, input

How to get an user input using scanner class and use it inside method to process, and obtain output?

Example : You get two numbers from the user and pass it to 4 methods to get its value after addition, subtraction, multiplication, division.

The scanner should be in main class and not inside every method.

Here is my code, it's in basic form. I want to get input from the user and process it inside the methods and get the result:

```
class Calc{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        add();
        sub();
        mul();
        div();
        {
            void Add() {
                int a=5,b=10;
                sum=a+b;
                System.out.println(sum);
            }
            void sub() {
                int a=5,b=10;
                sub=a=b;
                System.out.println(sub);
            }
            void mul() {
                int a=5,b=10;
                mul=a*b;
                System.out.println(mul);
            }
            void div() {
                int a=5,b=10;
                div=a/b;
                System.out.println(div);
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: seems like a home-work. Please provide the sample code you have written so far?

Comment: Yeah, it might sound like an home work, Am totally new in to programming.... 

Here it is, its in basic form, 

I want to get input from user and process it inside the methods and get result..


class Calc{
 public static void main(String[] args){
 add();
 sub();
 mul();
 div();
 
 {
 void Add()
 {
 int a=5,b=10;
 sum=a+b;
 System.out.println(sum);
 }
 void sub()
 {
 int a=5,b=10;
 sub=a=b;
 System.out.println(sub);
 }
 void mul()
 {
 int a=5,b=10;
 mul=a*b;
 System.out.println(mul);
 }
 void div()
 {
 int a=5,b=10;
 div=a/b;
 System.out.println(div);
 }
}
}
}

Comment: I added that in the question for you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the array or nextInt() method to get the number of input and passed it to your method.
For e.g. If you are supposed two take two input at time

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] integers = new int[2];
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
  integers[i] = sc.nextInt();
}
```

Now use the integers array to get the value from index and passed it to your method

Comment: Thank you for the reply :) 

Just to confirm, Is there any other way to pass the user input in to a method other than using for loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can get input by using `new Scanner(System.in)`, as follows:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int a = scanner.nextInt();
int b = scanner.nextInt();

add(a,b);
sub(a,b);
multiply(a,b);
divide(a,b);
```